# Use digital pins as analog - Arduino Micro

Tags: analogread, arduino-micro

I have an Arduino Micro and I want to use pin 6 and 8 as an analog pin, according to the manual this is possible:

> The Micro has a total of 12 analog inputs, pins from A0 to A5 are
>   labelled directly on the pins and the other ones that you can access
>   in code using the **constants** from A6 trough A11 are shared respectively
>   on digital pins 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, and 12.

What exactly do they mean by constants? I am aware what a constant is in the scope of programming, however I'm not sure what I should use to assign pins 6 and 8 as an analog pin? I assume I cannot just do an `analogRead(6)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constants are variables that cannot change. They are constant.

In this case they are variables that have been set up in the board definition files (in pins_arduino.h in case you're interested) and are named just as they have said - `A6` through `A11`.  This complements the existing `A0` through `A5` that are normally there anyway.

So you just use those names and it chooses the right pin for you:

```
int val = analogRead(A8);
```

The definitions of the pins are:

```
static const uint8_t A0 = 18;
static const uint8_t A1 = 19;
static const uint8_t A2 = 20;
static const uint8_t A3 = 21;
static const uint8_t A4 = 22;
static const uint8_t A5 = 23;
static const uint8_t A6 = 24;   // D4
static const uint8_t A7 = 25;   // D6
static const uint8_t A8 = 26;   // D8
static const uint8_t A9 = 27;   // D9
static const uint8_t A10 = 28;  // D10
static const uint8_t A11 = 29;  // D12
```

So no you cannot just use the number `8`, you have to use `A8` which points to pin number `26`. The Arduino core then interprets that number as an analog pin (as opposed to the digital pin, which is 8) and performs an analog read on it.

Comment: so conversely (and for my own understanding), to use these pins as a digital pin (which they are also capable of) I can also do a digitalRead(8)? Furthermore, is the 'A' required? I've read that it automatically assigns A if its an analogRead.

Comment: When referring to the pin in a digital context you can use either label.

Comment: If A8 equals 8 then they are interchangeable. If not, then not.

Comment: I guess I just found it strange that one pin could be used both as analog and as a digital!

Comment: I just looked the file up - you cannot use `8`, you have to use `A8` or `26`.

Comment: Good to know. I'll have to look at the pins_arduino file for future ref!

Comment: What are those pin numbers followed by ; ?

Comment: Yes, they are followed by ;